# How do I install the libssl1.0.0 package?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, software-installation

I am working on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ board with Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.9 (stretch) 
I am trying to install `libssl1.0.0` packages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

Later on I've even installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

But it's still not able to resolve the dependencies. How can I install `libssl1.0.0`?

Comment: a quick search shows `zipgateway` is only "available" for raspbian jessie

Answer (score 4):

Your installation says

```
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available ...
```

So just look what's available with

```
rpi ~$ apt list libssl*
Listing... Done
libssl-dev/oldstable 1.1.0k-1~deb9u1 armhf
libssl-doc/oldstable 1.1.0k-1~deb9u1 all
libssl-ocaml/oldstable 0.5.2-2 armhf
libssl-ocaml-dev/oldstable 0.5.2-2 armhf
libssl1.0-dev/oldstable 1.0.2s-1~deb9u1 armhf
libssl1.0.2/oldstable,now 1.0.2s-1~deb9u1 armhf
libssl1.1/oldstable,now 1.1.0k-1~deb9u1 armhf [installed]
```

Try to use `libssl1.0.2` instead of `libssl1.0.0`.

Comment: Hello, I have tried it to.. still getting error while Im running following command
sudo dpkg -i zipgateway-2.81.03-Linux-armhf.deb
ERROR :
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of zipgateway:
 zipgateway depends on libssl1.0.0; however:
  Package libssl1.0.0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package zipgateway (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

Comment: `zipgateway` doesn't seem to be a package available on the standard raspbian repos - where did you get that from?

Comment: @shivpatil Please read the comment from *@JaromandaX*.  Please edit your question and update it with the important information you have given in your comment.

Comment: actually zipgatewayis out application script which requires above mentioned packages as a dependencies.

Comment: @shivpatil Please add this information to the question as I suggested! It is an important information to understand your problem. You can edit the question.

Answer (score 4):

1. sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
2. add deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
3. sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
4. sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev

Comment: can vouch this is the hardcore way to make it work

Comment: `~$ sudo apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev
libssl1.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:`

and then get error as we can know from

`~$ sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0-dev is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0-dev' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 3):

I fixed with the steps below:

1. Download libssl1.0.0 from https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libssl1.0.0/download (I made this with WinScp tools, with a ssh connection with a Windows10 host).
2. In the folder containing this package run: dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_armhf.deb
3. Finally run: dpkg -i zipgateway-2.81.03-Linux-armhf.deb

For me it works

Comment: `~$ wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_armhf.deb`
 and get error as `~$ sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_armhf.deb
dpkg: error processing archive libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_armhf.deb (--install):
 package architecture (armhf) does not match system (amd64)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_armhf.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Using deb files written for Jessie can be problematic with mismatched dependencies, but if libssl-1.0.0 is the only missing one it has complained about so far, there's hope.

Here is a recipe to work around this not-too-uncommon error at your own risk:

```
ar xv zipgateway-2.81.03-Linux-armhf.deb

mkdir -p tmp
cd tmp
tar xvf ../control.tar.*
sed -i 's/libssl1.0.0/libssl1.1/' control
tar cJf ../control.tar.xz *
cd ..

ar cr zipgateway-2.81.03-Linux-armhf-patched.deb \
  debian-binary control.tar.xz data.tar.*
sudo apt install ./zipgateway-2.81.03-Linux-armhf-patched.deb
```

That may successfully install the package or may identify other missing dependencies to work through. Once you get around to running the program it's unlikely that it will depend on any OpenSSL 1.0.0-specific bugs at runtime, but there may be other incompatibilities taking a binary from Jessie to Stretch.

All the more reason you should put as much information as possible in your question description with regards to this particular zipgateway Jessie package.

Answer (score 1):

```
~:$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
~:$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:rael-gc/rvm
~:$ sudo apt-get update
~:$ sudo apt-get install rvm
~:$ sudo apt install libssl1.0-dev
```

Source: [`./configure` fails when using libssl-dev 1.1.0g #22](https://github.com/thispc/psiphon/issues/22#issuecomment-846551757)

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works:

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u7_armhf.deb

sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.2_1.0.2u-1~deb9u7_armhf.deb
```